# Issue using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this error while attempting to use useState within react:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPt7.png

I have:

- Reinstalled all modules
- Made sure they are all up to date
- Checked that I dont have duplicate react
- I have thoroughly gone through [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) website and nothing helps

Comment: There are few issues there. 1. In `home.js` you have a class component, hooks are allowed to use in function component only. 2. Trying to use `useState` in `render`. Suggested section from the documentation what you linked is [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: Like the error message says, "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." You don't have a function component, you have a class component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, "Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component," but you have a class component. You need to first [use a function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) rather than a class component, and then make sure you are calling `useState` from the top level of the component, not from another function inside of it.

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) includes this exact scenario as an example of why you would get this error:

[image: Bad hooks example]

Comment: "Move it outside of render()" is a bit misleading, the entire component needs to be rewritten as a function component.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading this documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

React hooks can **only** be used in a functional component and they should not be used in the return / render hook.

Try this:

```
function component() {
 const [gridMode, setGridMode] = useState(false);

 return() {
  <button onClick={()=> setGridMode(true)}>Change hook state!</button>
  //an example of how to manipulate your hook
 }
}
```